# Animation End event Zurb Foundation for apps

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, ng-animate

I have a scroll up event and a scroll down event.  I am trying to use FoundationAPI.animate to slideInUp a div on scroll up and then slideOutBottom on scroll down.  The original state of the div has a class of hide because without scrolling - it lives off the bottom of the page.  I have this working except for one problem.  When the slideOutBottom animation is finished, the hide class no longer is in the div, so it shows after the slideOutBottom completes.  I want it to stay hidden like it was at state 0.

Code:

```
$scope.scrollUp = function() {
  if ($scope.lock == false ){ 
    console.log('scrolling up');
    $scope.lock = true;
    FoundationApi.animate($('.footer-bar'), $state, "slideInUp", "hide");
    console.log($state);
  }
};
$scope.scrollDown = function() {
  if ($scope.lock == true){
    console.log('scrolling down');
    $scope.lock = false;
    FoundationApi.animate($('.footer-bar'), !$state, "hide", "slideOutBottom");
    // setTimeout(function() {
    //   $('.footer-bar').addClass('hide');
    // }, 999);
  }  
};
```

How do I access a callback for the FoundationAPI.animate(4) function such that it fires when it is complete?  The commented out timeout works, but after the slideOutBottom finishes, the footer-bar appears, then the hide class gets applied.  This causes the div to blink quickly.  Anyone?  The documentation on FoundationApi is lacking right now...

Comment: Yeah the apps documentation is in need of urgent love. A bit disappointing. Apps is clearly more complex than Foundation for Sites yet doesn't have the comparative docs for it. Comon Zurb!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a solution.  This a more natural AngularJS approach:

Controller:

```
 function myController($scope, ...) {
    $scope.lock = false;

    $scope.scrollUp = function() {
      if ($scope.lock == false ){ 
          $scope.lock = true;
          $scope.$apply();
       }
    };
    $scope.scrollDown = function() {
      if ($scope.lock == true){
          $scope.lock = false;
          $scope.$apply();
      }
    };
 }
```

View:

```
<a id="footer" class="slideInUp slideOutBottom footer-bar" ng-hide="lock" zf-open="myModal">
    <div>Click Me</div>
</a>
```

So the scroll events I bind with a directive on the particular view container; this determines the logic for when we detect the scroll up/down events.  From the directive I call these functions that are defined the scoped controller (above).  These are bound 2-ways with the "lock" variable accessible in this scope.

Note that the way the animations are triggered are with the classes in the anchor.  I think there are defined **enter** animations and defined **exit** animations which are both present in the class.  So ng-hide kicks in depending on the boolean value of the $scope.lock variable in my controller.

Totally not clear - I guess would be more clear to an Angular expert